# Highlight post in sidebar on single page

Tags: wp-query

When you have a menu for say pages, it's easy to highlight your current page, since WP puts a class on it.

But what I have is a sidebar with the 20 latest posts in a loop and a separate main content area for the normal page loop and single page/category page etc.

My sidebar loop looks like this.

```
<ul>
                    <?php
                        $sidebar_query = new WP_Query(array(
                            'showposts' => 20
                        ) );
                    ?>

                    <?php while ($sidebar_query->have_posts()) : $sidebar_query->the_post(); ?>

                        <li>
                        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) :?>
                            <div class="figure">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('sidethumb'); ?>
                            </div> <!-- end div figure //centers thumbnail -->
                        <?php else :?>
                        <?php endif;?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                <span class="theparentcat">
                        <?php
                            $cat_names = wp_list_pluck( get_the_category(), 'cat_name');
                            echo wp_sprintf_l( '%l', $cat_names );
                        ?>
                            </span>
                            <h2><?php the_title (); ?></h2>
                            <span class="thetime">
                                <?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?>
                            </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </ul>
```

Now, what'd be the best way (if there's a way) to highlight the current post when on a single page?
Now I could echo out a class or something in there, but then it'd be applied to all the posts in the loop so that'd be useless.

So I've got say,

Story one
Story two
Story three

in the sidebar and I'm on the page of story 1, how would one add a class to only that post so it can be highlighted with css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to add a class to the link that contains the post ID.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="post-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
```

You can then write a custom CSS function, put it in functions.php and hook to the wp_head. This function only serves to echo the necessary CSS to highlight the link.

```
function theme_prefix_highlight_current_post_in_sidebar() {
    if( is_single() ) {
        global $post;
    ?>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body.postid-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> a.post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> {
            color: #f00;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'theme_prefix_highlight_current_post_in_sidebar');
```

EDIT: On a sidenote, if you might want to add conditional checks like is_single() in this function to only display this on the pages where it is needed.

Comment: Well adding the echo get_the_id in on the permalink in the sidebar loop certainly shows the posts ID, but that function doesn't seem to do anything when I paste it in my sidebar, not on the single nor the index or any other page.

Comment: Please read my response. You need to put the function in the Theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Yes, that's where I put it! :p

Ah, I'm silly, it is spitting out a style in the themes header now.
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body.postid-453 a.post-453 {
        background-color: #f00;
    }
</style>

The problem is it's not styling the post, hrmm.

Comment: Ah nevermind, I'm being dopey because I didn't sleep last night, I change the echo to the containing li and forgot to change the function accordingly, now I've just got to work out how to make it work for single pages only!

Comment: It's all in my response. :) Just add if( is_single() ) { after the opening brace of the function and add a closing brace at the end of it. Like this the code will only be executed on single pages. And then you maybe can get some sleep.

Comment: That's not how you should print CSS into the head for a WordPress page, you should instead use the `wp_print_styles` action for(as the name suggests) printing styles. The user also has select conditions for when this sidebar is active, your code should abide by those same conditions. If you add each of those things to your answer you'll get my upvote.

Comment: Fair point about adding the is_single() check in the code. I'm not too sure about wp_print_styles though, since it runs after wp_head. If I remember correctly, Jetpack uses wp_head too to print custom CSS.